# find all the nodes of a binary tree from **root to leaf** which gives the sum equal to the target sum

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, find all the nodes from **root to leaf** which when added is equal to the target sum.
This algorithm works fine when used in python but when I'm using c++ it is throwing an error.

**ERROR**: invalid use of void expression at line 22 char 80:

```
       help(root->left, sum - root->val, temp.push_back(root->val), result);
```

here's my code.

```
    void help(TreeNode* root, int sum, vector<int>& temp, vector<vector<int>>& result)
    {
        if ((sum == root->val) and (not root->left and not root->right))
        {
            temp.push_back(root->val);
            result.push_back(temp);
            return;
        }

        if (root->left){
            help(root->left, sum - root->val, temp.push_back(root->val), result);
        }      // here i'm getting an error.

        if (root->right){
            help(root->right, sum - root->val, temp.push_back(root->val), result);
        }
    }

    vector<vector<int>> pathSum(TreeNode* root, int sum) {
        if (root == NULL)
           return;
        vector<vector<int>> result;
        vector<int> temp;
        help(root, sum, temp, result);
        return result;
    }
```

I don't understand how do I fix this error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

the code `temp.push_back(root->val)` returns `void` and the function `help` expects `vector`.

you should split the code into two lines as follows:

```
if (root->left) {
    temp.push_back(root->val);
    help(root->left, sum - root->val, temp, result);
}    

if (root->right) {
    temp.push_back(root->val);
    help(root->right, sum - root->val, temp, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler error arises due to imperfect boundary conditions to terminate the recursive calls, and not due to the highlighted code.

Comparator operators need correction in your code. Also, you can increase the efficiency of the code by ceasing further search, if the current sum is already greater than the target sum.

```
void help(TreeNode* root, int sum, vector<int>& temp, vector<vector<int>>& result)
{
        if ( sum == root->val &&  !root->left && !root->right )
        {
            temp.push_back(root->val);
            result.push_back(temp);
            return;
        }
        /* other codes*/
}
```